# JavaFX SceneBuilder Stylesheets

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

I am currently attempting to add a Stylesheet to my Scene via SceneBuilder, however currently I seem to be running into a few issues.

```
-fx-background-color:

        linear-gradient(#686868 0%, #232723 25%, #373837 75%, #757575 100%),
        linear-gradient(#020b02, #3a3a3a),
        linear-gradient(#9d9e9d 0%, #6b6a6b 20%, #343534 80%, #242424 100%),
        linear-gradient(#8a8a8a 0%, #6b6a6b 20%, #343534 80%, #262626 100%),
        linear-gradient(#777777 0%, #606060 50%, #505250 51%, #2a2b2a 100%);
```

Currently I am attempting to use that segment to colorize an `HBox` within my `Scene`.

A peek at my FXML if needed:

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <bottom>
      <HBox stylesheets="@styles/bottomRow.css" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="nameOfImage" text="nameOfImage" />
            <Region HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Label fx:id="sizeOfImage" text="sizeOfImage" />
         </children>
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </opaqueInsets>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
   <top>
      <VBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <MenuBar>
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </top>
   <center>
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Region prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <ImageView cacheHint="SCALE" depthTest="ENABLE" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" nodeOrientation="INHERIT" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <viewport>
                  <Rectangle2D />
               </viewport>
            </ImageView>
            <Region prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

I managed to use a linear gradient before, however I am not sure what is going wrong here. Currently it should color the `HBox` but currently it leaves it a white slate, without a hint of color. I tried finding better ways to use `.css` to see if that part was correct however they more or less look all the same.

Thought I'd post this last bit just in case:
[image: image thing]

Comment: Can you post a complete CSS file? Specifically, what selector are you using? What are the different insets corresponding to the five colors you defined?

Comment: The code for the CSS is the complete code in the file. It's all I've gotten to at this point.

I'm also not completely understanding what you mean by selector and insets as well. New to this stuff still, so I don't know many of the terms.

Comment: That's not a valid CSS file. The only thing you have there is a *rule*. A CSS file needs one or more *selectors*, and rules for each of the selectors. Have a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#CHDGHCDG), particularly the sections "Creating Style Sheets", "Defining Styles", and "Selectors".